# Global update data returned by ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, callback

I've a code like this:

```
$.get( "ajax/test.html", function( data ) {
  $( ".result" ).html( data );
});
```

I want to update the data returned by ajax using some global method

1. the code for updating a data will be loaded from the different file, so it can't be stored inside the current `$.get` function.
2. once data is updated by some global function, `$.get` should receive an updated code, not the original one
3. data should be updated for the `HTML` data only, not json or any other type of data

I know there's a global function available to handle success on ajax calls:

```
$(document).ajaxSuccess(function() {
  $( ".log" ).text( "Triggered ajaxSuccess handler." );
});
```

The problem is, this function just receives data, I'm not sure how the `data` can be updated through this function.

Any ideas?

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/ajaxSuccess/ shows how. The function gets passed the XMLHTTPRequest object, from which you can access the response.

Comment: @Felix Kling I don't see an answer on that link, any example?

Comment: NVM, I misunderstood the question.

Comment: *"the code for updating a data will be loaded from the different file"* You can still call a function defined in another file inside the `$.get` callback. That should not be a problem.

Comment: Can't you update the data then load the HTML file?

Comment: I'm searching for a way to update the data without touching `$.get`

Comment: @Qantas 94 Heavy nope

Comment: I don't understand the question -- what's the reason you're trying to do this?

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I simply don't have an access to `$.get`, but I need to update the `data` before it will travel forward to ajax callbacks.

Comment: there're some functions like http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxTransport/ and http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxPrefilter/, but I'm not sure how to play with them

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you can use [ajaxSetup](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajaxSetup/) function and set filter here like this:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
    converters: {
        'text html': function (data) {
            console.log('haha! I\'ve stolen your data!');
            console.log(data.substring(0,100));
            return 'no data :)';
        }
    }
});

$.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net')
.success(function(data) {
     console.log('I got:' + data);
});
```

In this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/5NyaV/) only html data will be changed.

**EDIT**:

I used filter for `text html` (contains 2 identifiers: `from` type and `to` type) because it is mentioned in jQuery docs:

> {"* text": window.String, "text html": true, "text json": jQuery.parseJSON, "text xml": jQuery.parseXML}

As I see it defines covertion from `text` to `html`. Usually there is no conversion, but you can add your own, which can modify data as you want.

**EDIT2**

If you want you can use the following "durty hack":

```
var originalFunc = $.get;
$.get = function() {
    return originalFunc.apply(window, arguments)
    .then(function(data) {
        return 'no data again :)';
    });
};
```

One more [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/ujsgH/).

Or, `dataFilter` as follows:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   dataFilter: function(data) {
        //console.log(data);
        return 'sorry, guys, I lost data again';
    }
});

$.get('http://fiddle.jshell.net')
.success(function(data) {
    console.log('I got:' + data);
});
```

Next [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/92EsU/).

Comment: looks like it works. Where did you get an info about converters? I'm also not sure about `text html` - will it convert both `text` and `html` or that is the name for the `html` output?

Comment: @Steve I read the jQuery docs :) Then I made a test and it worked! I guess you can do some experiments with types but I think it is a synonimous for HTML.

Comment: your solution is pretty great, but I'm not sure if it's safe to use data in the way like data.somepluginmethod();

Comment: I tried other types and it's seems we need exactly `text html`. `ajaxSetup` uses the same object structure as `ajax` function. See here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: I don't see any weak points here, it's a global handler, which is designed for such purposes. Just make it safe (it depends on your code) and use it.

Comment: corresponding to the docs, converters in your example converts `text` data type to `html` data type. I'm not sure what they actually mean

Comment: the issue is, if user sets `html` as dataType, converter may not work

Comment: `text html` also doesn't work when I try to update the HTML returned by data

Comment: @Steve Ok, I just give you suggestions which works for me. See my updated answer with 2 more approaches and 2 more demos. Hope you will find one best for you. But notice that next 2 approaches demand you to handle requested type manually. In my demos I just replace data, your code should be more smart to choose which data need to modified and which doesn't.

Comment: so how do I use jquery functions inside dataFilter: function(data){} ?

Comment: There is only one way for this: parse data, change it, using jQuery, and convert back to string. Here is the demo: http://jsfiddle.net/92EsU/1/ In demo I remove all script elements, you can modify document as you want.